# Drawing a histogram from a file

Tags: bash, awk, histogram

I am working on school project and I dont know how to draw histogram with AWK.

this is what I need:

Variable1 (8): ########
Variable2 (4): ####
Variable3 (2): ##
Variable4 (2): ##
Variable5 (2): ##
Variable6 (1): #
Variable7 (1): #
Variable8 (1): #

```sh
awk '{n[$1]++} END {for (i in n) print i,"("n[i]"):"} file | sort -n
```

Variable1 (8):
Variable2 (4):
Variable3 (2):
Variable4 (2):
Variable5 (2):
Variable6 (1):
Variable7 (1):
Variable8 (1):

so I need to add **#s**

Comment: Post some sample data that is supposed to produce that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    { n[$1]++ }
    END {
        for (i in n) {
            bar = sprintf("%*s",n[i],"")
            gsub(/ /,"#",bar)
            printf "%d\t%s (%d): %s\n", n[i], i, n[i], bar
        }
    }
' file | sort -rn | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk. In the lack of proper sample data using numbers as such:

```
$ cat file
8
4
...
```

Awk:

```
$ awk '{h=sprintf("%0" $1 "d",0);gsub(/0/,"#",h);print $1,h}' file
```

Output:

```
8 ########
4 ####
2 ##
2 ##
2 ##
1 #
1 #
1 #
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    h=sprintf("%0" $1 "d",0)  # use 0s for the histogram chars
    gsub(/0/,"#",h)           # replace with #s
    print $1,h                # output
}' file
```

Comment: Another way is `bar = sprintf("%*s", $1, ""); gsub(/ /, "#", bar)` -- only advantage is passing the width as an argument to sprintf instead of dynamically constructing the format string.